# Get the current pathname of Dash plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to print and get the current path of the URL in Dash in order do to a filter.

I tried to with print(Input('url', 'pathname')) but but don't get the URL.

Any idea please ?
Thanks

Edit__________ :

I tried this , but I keep getting the pathname each second. How to stop it and get just one time the pathname ?

```
html.Div(id='print')

@app.callback(
    Output('print', 'children'),
    [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def callback_func(pathname):
print(pathname)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the rest of your code, I don't know what triggers your callback. `Input('url', 'pathname')` only fires a callback when the url is loaded.

```py
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output


app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([html.Div(id='print'), dcc.Location(id='url')])


@app.callback(
    Output('print', 'children'),
    [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def callback_func(pathname):
    print(pathname)
    return pathname


app.run_server()
```

If you have other inputs that trigger your callback and you only need the url when they do so, you can change the type from `Input` to `State`. This lets you access the pathname as a variable in your function, but doesn't ever fire a callback:

```py
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, State


app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='print'),
    dcc.Location(id='url'),
    html.Button('print', id='button')
])


@app.callback(
    Output('print', 'children'),
    Input('button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('url', 'pathname'))
def callback_func(_, pathname):
    print(pathname)
    return pathname


app.run_server()
```

Comment: Thank you ! you answered perfectly my question.